# Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to 'NSNumber'

Tags: ios, swift, double, nsjsonserialization

I have a Swift struct like this.

```
struct Usage {
    var totalData: Double
    var remainingTotalData: Double

    init(jsonData: NSData) {
        var jsonDict = [String: AnyObject]()

        do {
            jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
        } catch {
            print("Error occurred parsing data: \(error)")
        }

        totalData = jsonDict["totalfup"] as! Double
        remainingTotalData = jsonDict["totalrem"] as! Double
    }
}
```

From an API, I get the following JSON response. This is the println of the `jsonDict` variable.

```
[
    "totalfup": 96.340899, 
    "totalrem": 3548710948
]
```

When I try to assign the value of the `totalfup` to the property `totalData`, I get this error.

**Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to 'NSNumber'**

Anyone knows why? I tried changing the property type to `float` and then the whole struct to class but still the issue occurs.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The reason of the error is `jsonDict["totalfup"]` is a String (`NSTaggedPointerString` is a subclass of `NSString`) , so you should convert String to Double.

**Please make sure, catch exception and check type before force-unwrap !**

```
totalData = (jsonDict["totalfup"] as! NSString).doubleValue
```

For **safety**, using `if let`:

```
// check dict["totalfup"] is a String?
if let totalfup = (dict["totalfup"] as? NSString)?.doubleValue {
  // totalfup is a Double here 
}
else {
  // dict["totalfup"] isn't a String
  // you can try to 'as? Double' here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Do you know why this is? Back in Swift 1.2, we didn't have to convert to `NSString`s, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about Swift 1.2. But `NSJSONSerialization` sometimes deserialize number value as number. For sure, before converting values from `NSDecimalNumber `, let check [object class] (dynamicType) first.

Comment: I got the same error with a framework I was using that reads configuration values from a custom plist file in the bundle's resources (no JSON involved). I had defined some of the plist fields as `String`s, but they API was likely expecting them to be  `Number`s. Changing the type to `Number` fixed the issue.

Comment: Happened to me recently. Make sure whatever outputs your data is in fact the Type you're expecting. On a database I was doing a `SUM()` operation between integers and apparently the result is always a `Double`, which PHP reads as a `String`.

Answer (score 21):

I think this could help you

```
totalData = Double(jsonDict["totalfup"] as! String)!
```

Answer (score 5):

The failure reason is that the JSON returns `String` values, not numbers.

If the returned JSON data contains only these two key value pairs declare the type as `[String:String]` that avoids the type casting.

In any case you have to put the code to update the variables into the "good" branch of the `do - catch` expression.

```
struct Usage {
    var totalData = 0.0
    var remainingTotalData = 0.0

    init(jsonData: NSData) { // Swift 3: Data

        do {
            let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [String: String]                
            // Swift 3: let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! [String: String]
            totalData = Double(jsonDict["totalfup"]!)
            remainingTotalData = Double(jsonDict["totalrem"]!)
        } catch {
            print("Error occurred parsing data: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I can't simply do `Double(jsonDict["totalfup"])` as I get this error. **Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject?)'**. I guess you have to define key value pair type as `[String: Double]` in order this to work.

Comment: if `jsonDict` is casted to ` [String: String]` (see end of the `NSJSONSerialization` line in my answer) the compiler cannot assume it's `AnyObject`. However I forgot the exclamation marks yo unwrap the values

Comment: @vadian please update your answer, otherwise it will not compile ... (all properties must be initialized)

Answer (score 0):

**Tested and Working for Swift 5.0.**

I had the same problem.

This worked for me.

```
// check dict["dummy"] is a String first
if let receivedData = (dict["dummy"]).doubleValue {
  // add more code in case the condition is true
}
else {
 // add more code in case the condition is false
}
```

It is really helpful when you want to compare the received data or just check the value like the following example.

```
let receivedData = (results["data"]!).doubleValue

if (receivedData == 0){
      self.label.text = "Nothing seem to be added yet!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### String interpolation

I posted [my answer in a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322463/8845253).

```
if let jsonDict_any = jsonDict["totalfup"], 
   let jsonDict_double = Double("\(jsonDict_any)") {
   //..
}
```

Essentially, this avoids having to try multiple typecastings. By checking first for its existence, we can can then use string interpolation, then try casting it to a Double.

#### Warning:

As @Alexander pointed out, this solution allows *any* `Type` to become a `String` and be checked for a `Double` value. Only use this if you're not concerned about the value's `Type` prior to interpolation.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend doing `"\(jsonDict_any)"`. You're in for some surprises, when the `jsonDict_any` value isn't a String like you might expect. String interpolation value will turn *any* value into a string, whether it makes sense to, or not. This may sound convenient, but it obscures bugs. Casting is the correct way to go.

Comment: that's why it's wrapped inside an `if let`, as casting whatever is interpolated to a `Double` might fail and return `nil`.

Comment: The problem *I* was personally having was that casting to a String didn't work if the value was correctly getting decoded as a number. My proposed solution works if it's either a (numeric) String or a number, and fails otherwise.

Comment: Yes, but the interpolation might fail you reasons you didn't anticipate, and it's not necessary a good idea to handle those reasons the same way. For example, perhaps you wanted it to fail the `if let` if jsonDict_any was `"not a number"`. But if one day it happened to have a value of `false`, it would still hit the same path and not be parsed into a number. The issue is, your datasource was changed in a way that lets it vend data you didn't expect, and you wouldn't be made aware of that change because it was handled silently as if it were any other not-a-valid-number value.

Comment: What was the value and type of `jsonDict_any` in your case?

Comment: In my case, I had two values in my dictionary, both numbers coming from a database. After decoding the json on iOS, one passed the `if let x = dict['x'] as? Int` code (so I think that decoded correctly as an `NSNumber`), the other didn't pass with the same syntax. Error was same as OP's title. I am only ever expecting an integer value from these two specific fields, so my solution allowed both an `NSTaggedPointerString` and `NSNumber` to be cast as `Int` (because casting `as? String` failed for the NSNumber value).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234710/discussion-between-alexander-and-merricat).

Answer (score -1):

why not use Swift's native types directly?

```
import Foundation

struct Usage {
    var totalData: Double = 0
    var remainingTotalData: Double = 0

    init(jsonData: NSData) {
        do {
            if let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as? [String:Double] {
                totalData = jsonDict["totalfup"] ?? 0
                remainingTotalData = jsonDict["totalrem"] ?? 0
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error occurred parsing data: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

if let data = "{\"totalfup\":96.340899,\"totalrem\":3548710948}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    let usage = Usage(jsonData: data)
    dump(usage)
    /*
    ▿ Usage
      - totalData: 96.340899
      - remainingTotalData: 3548710948.0
    */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

## Swift 4

```
    let strStatus:String = dictProperty.value(forKey: "StatusType") as! String
    let myStatus = Double.init(strStatus)
```

## Update

```
extension String {
    func toDouble() -> Double? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return numberFormatter.number(from: self)?.doubleValue
    }

    func toInt() -> Int? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return numberFormatter.number(from: self)?.intValue
    }

    func toFloat() -> Float? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return numberFormatter.number(from: self)?.floatValue
    }

    func toBool() -> Bool? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return numberFormatter.number(from: self)?.boolValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Force casting is rarely a good idea.. This is one of the many times where it's not recommended and could cause the application to crash unexpectedly.

Comment: @ZGski it is a just convert string to double value, Please check your api side data type, (is should must be string data type not number, not bool, or other params just string), then it is work

Comment: Any way I just add new string extension this will also help to convert string to double value, Please check my updated answer