# Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x10146ecd8) to 'NSNumber' (0x102675600)

Tags: swift, class, object, nstaggedpointerstring

I am trying to make a loop in my code like this:

```
for row in rows! {
        print("Row",row)
        let pin = Pin.init(latitude: row[0] as! Float, longitude: row[1] as! Float, pinType: row[2] as! String, beaconID: row[3] as! Int, altitude: row[4] as! Float)
        pinList.append(pin)
    }
```

Here, row is an `Any` and I'm creating the pin object based on the row's values.

Here is my Pin Class:

```
class Pin {
    var latitude:Float
    var longitude:Float
    var pinType:String
    var beaconID:Int
    var altitude:Float

    init(latitude:Float, longitude:Float, pinType:String, beaconID:Int, altitude:Float){
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.pinType = pinType
        self.beaconID = beaconID
        self.altitude = altitude
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

> Could not cast value of type '`NSTaggedPointerString`' (0x10146ecd8) to '`NSNumber`' (0x102675600).

while I am trying to create the Pin object.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please show the output of `print("Row",row)`

Comment: Here is the value of Row [1.283364, 103.815021, yellow, 1, 20]. I found the way to solve unexpectedly :) thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to 'NSNumber'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299202/could-not-cast-value-of-type-nstaggedpointerstring-to-nsnumber)

Comment: Yes I have also found that solution and already fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
id = Int((content[0]["id"] as! NSString).floatValue)
```

This works fine for me. Content is json array

Answer (score 0):

Unexpectedly, I found the answer by reading along the many documentations.
Here is the solution for this problem.

```
for row in rows! {
        print("Row",row)
        let lat = (row[0] as! NSString).floatValue
        let lng = (row[1] as! NSString).floatValue
        let pType = (row[2] as! NSString) as String
        let bID = (row[3] as! NSString).integerValue
        let alti = (row[4] as! NSString).floatValue

        let pin = Pin.init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng, pinType: pType, beaconID: bID, altitude: alti)
        pinList.append(pin)
    }
```

I tried to convert all the values from row to NSString first and convert the result to the types that I really convert to. :)

Comment: Bridging to `NSString` (and even back to `String`) is a very bad solution.