# Unable to extract data properly from JSON in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a this kind of json object in my response after parsing json string to object

```
[
    "requestId": 1, 
    "response": {
        code = SUCCESS;
    }, 
    "messageId": ACTION_COMPLETE
]
```

I am trying to extract `requestId` using

```
responseMsg["requestId"] as! Int
```

I am getting this error

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x21877a910) to
>   'NSNumber' (0x218788588).

I tried it changing to `Int(responseMsg["requestId"] as! String)!`
This thing is working for positive numbers but not for negative numbers probably bcz when `requestId = -2` it throws me an error

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x21877a000) to
>   'NSString' (0x218788290).

I tried with different other solution too but did not work.

Comment: does the json return `"1"` or just `1`

Comment: The JSON is an array or dictionary?

Comment: that json is exactly same that has come in swift log @CerlinBoss

Comment: json representation lot messy in swift @PGDev

Comment: Is your response will have same data always ?, if so please use `decodable stuct`

Comment: response object structure can change

Comment: If negative numbers are sent as number and positive as string it's a server side bug. Ask the owner of the service to send consistent data.

Comment: requestId is coming as number only

Comment: the crash shows it's a string not a number

Comment: @Sh_Khan but it is not a string.

Answer (score 2):

For parsing the *JSON data*, its better use **`Codable`** instead of manually parsing everything.

For **JSON format**,

```
{
    "requestId": 1,
    "response": {
        "code":"SUCCESS"
    },
    "messageId": "ACTION_COMPLETE"
}
```

Create **Models** like,

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let requestId: String?
    let messageId: String
    let response: Response

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case requestId, messageId, response
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let id = try? values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .requestId) {
            requestId = String(id)
        } else if let id = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .requestId) {
            requestId = id
        } else {
            requestId = nil
        }
        messageId = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .messageId)
        response = try values.decode(Response.self, forKey: .response)
    }
}
```

Now, **parse** the *JSON data* using,

```
do {
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(root.requestId) //access requestId like this....
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: if `requestId` type changes then this will give a decoding error

Comment: My Response will be like this
struct Response: Decodable {
    let code: String, let data : [String : Any]
} .        but it is showing error

Comment: @Sh_Khan Why would the type change if the JSON response is like this,

Comment: Type 'Response' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Comment: the above is a console log not a json structure so no way to know type of `requestId`

Comment: @RateM The error is because Codable doesn't support Any type. You need to give the type as a specific data type that you're expecting.

Comment: @Sh_Khan The code will work for a particular type. If the type is Int same code can be used and if it is String, the type in the above code can be changed. Also , it is not mentioned that we need to handle multiple types.

Comment: why not use the optional property in a struct?

Comment: @Sh_Khan is correct. It is issue of url scheme i think coz it is giving quotes for positive number and no quotes for negative number. I was using url scheme to get the json object

Comment: I got some simple implementation for Decoder. Thanks @PGDev

Comment: @RateM if that is the case, you can handle that with init in struct Root. Updated the code with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Int(String(describing: responseMsg["requestId"]))!
```

This ensures any data is converted to string first and then to int

Comment: String typecasting is giving nil

Answer (score 0):

This error message

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x21877a910) to 'NSNumber' (0x218788588).
```

tells us that the JSON  request id is being parsed as a string. `NSTaggedPointerString` is a special internal type used by the ObjC runtime to represent strings.

Try this:

```
let requestId = responseMsg["requestId"] as! String
print("request id: \(requestId)") // Prints a string
```

Note, it may print something that looks like a number, but it isn't one.

The JSON you are parsing probably looks like

```
{
    "requestId": "1", 
    "response": {
        "code" = "SUCCESS"
    }, 
    "messageId": "ACTION_COMPLETE"
}
```

Note the `1` in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5

**String interpolation** is what worked for me! (casting it first to `String` didn't work as I had other values for which the json decoder *actually* did its job and cast them directly to a number)

```
if let responseMsg_any = responseMsg["requestId"], 
   let responseMsg_int = Int("\(responseMsg_any)") {
   //..
}
```

#### Warning:

This solution allows *any* `Type` to become a `String` and be checked for a `Int` value. Only use this if you're not concerned about the value's `Type` prior to interpolation.